# Why Can't Magento support "Visa Debit" card on payment page?

Tags: magento2, payment

I have a website on Magento 2.2 and some customers wanted to use Visa Debit Card in the "Credit or Debit Card" payment option but they couldn't use a Visa debit card.

I'm wondering why they can not use the Visa Debit card in payment method?

Answer (score 0):

To accept Visa cards, make sure that it is selected as an allowed credit card type. You can check the setting under Store>Settings>Configuration>Sales>Payment Methods. If Visa is not highlighted, then you need to select it and save the configuration and clear your cache.

Comment: Actually customer can use "Visa" card but customers can not use "Visa Debit" card. That's the issue.

Comment: Which payment method are you using?

Comment: "PayFlow from Paypal" - Website Payments Pro

Comment: If you call PayPal support they can check to see if the transactions are going through on their end or if something is blocking them then they can also see that and let you know. 1-888-221-1161

Comment: Thank you! will reach out to Paypal support.

Comment: Were you able to get this fixed?